# Can't Open XIB in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4.4

I get this message from Xcode when I try to edit the xib for one of my apps.

> _The document "ViewController_iPhone.xib" could not be opened. This version of Xcode does no support Auto Layout for iOS documents. Edit
>   this document with a newer version of Xcode.

I have Xcode version "4.4"

Comment: Try opening with a text editor... could be a corrupt file (e.g. source control marks <<<<<)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have this problem if the XIB file was originally created in Xcode version 4.5+ (current preview version as of now is 4.5).  Auto Layout is a new feature that wasn't supported previously with older versions of Xcode.

Go to the developer portal and download 4.5 Preview Xcode and try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

1. Right click on .xib file -> open as "Source Code".
2. Find & delete object (some int/Hex) from xib source code.
3. Save File.
4. Again right click & open xib as "Interface Builder".

It will open your corrupt .xib file & u will not loss whole update in project.